# Problem with subdivision modifier

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface

So im was modeling a car front, but then i noticed that there is some smooth edge what i dont want. How to fix it?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add 2 edge loops in order to sharpen:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can either add support edges like the other person suggested, or you can use edge creases. Select those two corner edges, go to edge > edge crease and ramp it up to the maximum.

Edit: I've just noticed the car part has thickness. If you smooth the mesh after the extrusion into 3d, you need to crease all 5 corner edges, just a heads up. And if you crease before extrusion into 3d you actually need to crease the two edges inside the mesh pointing into the corner, not the external edges.

Answer (score 2):

to fix your problem you can simply add an edge loop to sharpen the smooth edges please follow these instruction
like this[image]

the image shown is a n example of a hard surface model being smoothened with a subdivision surface modifier
Notice how the edges are so circular?

[image]
so you should add an edge loop by pressing control+R on your keyboard.Then you would find an extra edge on your mesh the push it down to your edge which is soft and circular.

[image]

something like this
[image]

[image]
in your case you should add the edge loops here

Hope this helped